# Difficulty creating a dict that contains lists of values

Tags: python, dictionary

> Now let's write a couple functions that we can use going forward. We'll write a function called m_b_data that given a slope of a line,   , a y-intercept,   , will return a dictionary that has a key of x pointing to a list of x_values, and a key of y that points to a list of y_values. Each    value should be the output of a regression line for the provided    and    values, for each of the provided x_values.

What I have written:

```
def m_b_data(m, b, x_values):
    y_values = {}
    for x in x_values:
       y_values = {"X Values": x, "Y Values": (m*x)+b}   

    return y_values
```

The arguments passed into it:

```
m_b_data(1.5, 20, [0, 50, 100])
```

My output for this:

```
{'X Values': 100, 'Y Values': 170.0}
```

and what it should output:

```
{'x': [0, 50, 100], 'y': [20.0, 95.0, 170.0]}
```

To my understanding, in my `for` loop I am only actually copying in the final values. What I am guessing is happening is that I am just constantly rewriting the first key/value pair of the dictionary. I am not appending the dictionary to add new values but just constantly overwriting the first pair. Is that right?

How do I write the loop so that it creates lists with multiple X and Y values?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When one comes from a C++ or Java background it's a natural tendency to write a lot of explicit loops over collections. That's not the Python way. It's often possible to streamline these loops with strategic use of list comprehensions and generator expressions. Your code will often end up shorter and easier to follow, a nice win/win.

Let's try that approach and build our way up to a loop-less version. In your program you're trying to build a dict. Let's see if we can return one directly. We'll fill out the pieces a step at a time. First, a dict:

```
return {
    ???
}
```

A dict with two key/value pairs:

```
return {
    "X Values": ???,
    "Y Values": ???,
}
```

Now what? What goes in the placeholders? Well, the first one is the list of X values. You already have that: it's `x_values`. No need to iterate over each `x` in `x_values`. Let's just put it directly in the dict.

```
return {
    "X Values": x_values,
    "Y Values": ???,
}
```

What do we do for the Y values? Here's where list comprehensions come in. You want to apply the formula `y = m*x+b` to each `x` value. We can do that all in one line, both applying the formula and building the list at the same time:

```
return {
    "X Values": x_values,
    "Y Values": [m*x+b for x in x_values],
}
```

And we're done. Ain't Python grand?

Comment: This is some sort of wizardry. I really am enjoying Python, but it is a completely different mindset at this point. I am used to writing a loop for everything, and now I am learning that there are methods and features of the language that require nothing as explicit.

Answer (score 1):

You are overwriting `y_values` each time when you write `y_values = ...`. According to what you say you want to output, your code should be:

```
def m_b_data(m, b, x_values):
    y_values = {'x': [], 'y': []}
    for x in x_values:
        y_values['x'].append(x)
        y_values['y'].append(m * x + b)   

    return y_values
```

Answer (score 1):

The thing is that in your for loop you are always overwriting the y_values dictionary (with only one key-value pair) instead of adding items to it.

Your code should look more like this:

```
def m_b_data(m, b, x_values):
    y_values = []
    for x in x_values:
         y_values.append((m*x)+b)

    return {
        "X": x_values,
        "Y": y_values,
    }
```

First, you declare a list and loop through the x_values list to add the resulting y values to that list.

Then you create the dictionary, which will be:

"X": [List of x_values]

"Y": [list of y-values]

(Of course this is considering that the input x_values is a list, if it were a dictionary you would need to make some changes, but I assumed it was a list because thats the way you used it in your call:

```
m_b_data(1.5, 20, [0, 50, 100])
```